# TypeError: text.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection-api

Hi I'm trying to get selected value of a input when input is focused with tab. This is my code,

HTML,

```
<input id='texteb' type="text" value=''/>
<button>
  click
</button>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var focused = $(':focus');

    if (e.which === 9){
            var text = focused;
            var t = text.value.substring(text.selectionStart, text.selectionEnd - text.selectionStart);
            alert(t);
    }        
  });
});
```

But I'm getting this error,

> TypeError: text.value is undefined

This is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vimuths/7fzk6tpo/10/) for it.

With answers this issue can be solved with .val() but **selectionStart** seems to be giving undef

Comment: you need to use `.val()` instead of `.value` in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked over you fiddle an changed line 6: [jsfiddle - modified](https://jsfiddle.net/6dqgz1vw/)

```
//var text = focused;
var text = focused[0];
```

The reason you were getting `undefined` was that you were grabbing a jQuery object (i.e. "focused") that doesn't have those properties (`value`, `selectionStart` etc.). However, what you really needed was the javascript object, which is available using `focused[0]`.

For more methods, check this:
[How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/) (from: https://learn.jquery.com/)

(ps. I wonder what you are doing with this code?)

Comment: Thanks broo I'm using this code for read this text with speech synthesis api